# Is this a good goto-statement in c++?

Tags: c++, goto

Pseudo code:

```
if(testval == 1){
    routine_a:
        result = funcA();
} else {
    result = funcB();
    if(result.failed)
        goto routine_a;
}
// process result ...
```

Is this a good programming practice?
Or is there a better way to do this better than goto-statement?

Comment: Any `goto` is no good in C++.

Comment: @iBug That is an opinion and why almost every goto question is closed as opinion based on this site.

Comment: @iBug I would rather say "almost any `goto` is no good in C++". In C++, almost any best-practice statement is not valid absolutely.

Comment: Pretty much the only place where I'd use a goto is to jump out of a nested loop, that is go downwards in code, never upwards...

Comment: If you have to ask if `goto` is the right solution, it probably isn't.

Answer (score 6):

You can avoid duplicating the condition and avoid `goto` too by factoring this out into a separate function. Inside that separate function:

```
if (testval != 1) {
    auto result = funcB();
    if (!result.failed)
        return result;
}

return funcA();
```

Comment: I can't just return result of funcA or funcB, see the comment of psudeo code `// process result ...`, so basicly your idea just like @Yunnosch 's.

Comment: Don't just look at the code, read the sentence before it too. You wouldn't do this in the function you have, but in a new function which you call from the existing one.

Comment: The art of programming is to take a problem, and make it other smaller problems... repeatedly.  This answer is a nice example of that concept applied;  have an upvote.

Answer (score 2):

No this is not good. You should never `goto` backwards like this, it is a bad habit that can cause you to skip initialization of code etc which can lead to undefined behaviour. Why not just:

```
if(testval != 1){
    result = funcB();
}

if (testval == 1 || result.failed) { 
    result = funcA();
}
```

Comment: This is correct but very easy to get wrong, since it requires you to perfectly invert the logic in the condition. If it's anything more than a simple `==`, expect people to get it wrong.

Comment: @hvd True, but getting anything with a `goto` wrong is even easier.

Comment: You can get wrong reading the code, too. However, the whole discussion is heavily opinion based.

Answer (score 2):

Turning  the logic around will allow you this:

```
if(testval != 1){
    result = funcB();
}
if((testval==1)||(result.failed)){
    result = funcA();
}
```

Comment: Why shouldn't make `result.failed` sense? Obviously `result` is a structure type.

Comment: Whoa, way too many parentheses! `if (testval==1||result.failed)`.

Comment: @PeteBecker Thank you for sharing your opinion. For beginners and in a larger group of programmers of unknown experience (most any company), I prefer to be explicit about operator precedence. I know the "learning precedences by heart is worth the effort" reasoning (and actually agree), but I have lost too much time and money looking for bugs caused by mistakes here or for debugging discussions (even/especially when the problem later turned out to be elsewhere).

Comment: @Yunnosch -- (((writing code) that's (hard to read)) (because (people (expect) it) (doesn't make sense)).

Comment: @Yunnosch -- I **did not** recommend "learning precedences by heart", despite your misleading quotation marks. The expressions **in the code in question** are **basic** stuff. Parentheses around a simple member function call are just a distraction. Same thing for parentheses around a comparison expression.

Comment: @Yunnosch -- code is read far more often than it is written. To be a bit snarky: if you don't have time to do it right, when will you have time to fix it? <g>

Comment: @PeteBecker Yunnosch Yes, the number of parentheses is an important problem of information technology. You should discuss this to the end. And when you are done with that, start a discussion about spaces between operators and then a discussion about indention. Scientist will thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I personally would simply make it clear that you want to call funcA twice (in two places, not calling it twice, it only ever gets called once, but from two potential places).

So:

```
if(testval == 1){
        result = funcA();
} else {
    result = funcB();
    if(result.failed)
    {
        result = funcA();
    }
}
```

There is very little to be gained from using a goto here, and this makes it clear what you actually want to have happen - call FuncA under two quite different conditions.

Comment: Neither OPs code nor your code will call `funcA()` (or `FuncA()`) twice.

Comment: yes, but calling functions can have side effects, so as a maintenance effort, we may avoid even writing it twice to avoid inadvertent changes by other developers. See my answer

Comment: @nolan It's about following the logical flow. Obviously, this is potentially a contrived example, and the reality more complex, but it's still about making it clear what is happening. As my comment on your solution, that's not easy to follow. I expect, like most people, that in a switch, the cases are independent, not falling through. Yes, there are situations where falling through is the right thing to do.

Comment: Perhaps you’re right, I have updated my answer. Thanks for the input

Answer (score 0):

`if( testval == 1 || (testval=funcB()).failed ) testval=funcA();`

---

or you can do this (or with some flag)

```
testval.failed = true;
if(testval == 1)testval=funcB();
if(testval.failed)testval=funcA();
```

Answer (score 0):

> this is a good programming practice?

Depends on you, your team if you have one, your organization if you work for one.

Where I work, we haven't used `goto` anywhere in our code base consisting of about 4000 source files. It's a matter of opinion but code is less readable and maintainable with `goto` statements.

Given your snippet of code, you can easily use:

```
if(testval == 1){
   result = funcA();
} else {
   result = funcB();
   if(result.failed)
   {
      result = funcA();
   }
}
```